# How to adjust content in container in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm having problem adjusting iframe in container. It looks like this:[image]

as you can see the iframe does not have full width and i don't know why.

```
<div class="container container-kontakt-map">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2653.988373019885!2d18.06349931521357!3d48.303075047599364!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x476b3f0675b17005%3A0xd42d09b53f2f872f!2sPoliklinika+Kloko%C4%8Dina%2C+Hviezdoslavova+trieda+1%2C+949+11+Nitra!5e0!3m2!1sen!2ssk!4v1451834396880" width="100%" height="400px" frameborder="" style=""></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is html and here is css:

```
  .container-kontakt-map {
margin-top: 70px;
width: 100%;
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Container has a padding, you need to get rid of it or set it as negative number in iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting the element in the console and you will see that container from Bootstrap has padding/margin. You can take off the container class to achieve full width result.

```
<div class="row container-kontakt-map">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2653.988373019885!2d18.06349931521357!3d48.303075047599364!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x476b3f0675b17005%3A0xd42d09b53f2f872f!2sPoliklinika+Kloko%C4%8Dina%2C+Hviezdoslavova+trieda+1%2C+949+11+Nitra!5e0!3m2!1sen!2ssk!4v1451834396880" width="100%" height="400px" frameborder="" style=""></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Bootstrap Container](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container)

Comment: Bootstrap is a phone first framework. Instead of col-md-12, replace it with col-xs-12 and it will apply the same rule upwards from xs-*  thru lg-*. If you start from the higher devices, you won't have as much control over the sm-* or xs-*. This hurts responsiveness.

Answer (score 1):

Container has a padding/margin, you need to get rid of it.

```
<div class="container-kontakt-map">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2653.988373019885!2d18.06349931521357!3d48.303075047599364!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x476b3f0675b17005%3A0xd42d09b53f2f872f!2sPoliklinika+Kloko%C4%8Dina%2C+Hviezdoslavova+trieda+1%2C+949+11+Nitra!5e0!3m2!1sen!2ssk!4v1451834396880" width="100%" height="400px" frameborder="" style=""></iframe>
</div>
```